# Displaying Children of several pages

Tags: php

I have some code that works to display the children of a single page. I'm using this to display the children of a page in my footer.

```
$args = [
'post_type'=>'page', //this is the custom post type
'child_of'=> '1452',
];

// we get an array of posts objects
$posts = get_posts($args);

// start our string
$str = '<ul>';

// then we create an option for each post

foreach($posts as $key=>$post){
$str .= '<li><a href=" '.get_permalink($post).' ">'.$post->post_title.'</a> 
</li>';
}
$str .= '</ul>';

echo $str;
}
```

But I want to display the children of several pages - and when I try to use several instances of the code, of course, it displays only the first ID.

I've tried changing this into a function - but I can't get it to work. This is probably a very stupid question, but I'm a small-time PHP hack.

---

EDIT: I've just seen that it is not only pulling children from the page ID I have specified, it's pulling a few from everywhere. Very strange.

Comment: after each instance use `wp_reset_postdata();`

Comment: Hmm - tried inserting that after the final echo - but no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working code. If you place the code in proper place it will surely gonna work [inshALLAH]. You can use this as a function or even shortcode.

```
global $post;
$parent_id = $post->ID; //if you are within a loop

$childpages = new WP_Query([
                            'post_type'     => 'page',
                            'post_parent'   => intval( $parent_id ),
                            'posts_per_page'=> 3, // your choice
                            'orderby'       => 'menu_order', // your choice
                            'post_status'   => 'publish'
                        ]);

if( $childpages->have_posts() ) :
    echo '<ul>';
        while( $childpages->have_posts() ) : $childpages->the_post();
            echo '<li><a href="'. esc_url(get_the_permalink()) .'" rel="bookmark">'. esc_html(get_the_title()) .'</a></li>';
        endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
    echo '</ul>';
endif;
```

#### Further Reading

- [`WP_Query()` class — WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

Comment: This works for me - fantastic. Thanks for helping out a PHP noob!

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code, The `$args` should be a php array. And, `post_parent` argument should be used instead of `child_of`.

Try this..

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'page',
    'post_parent' => 1452,
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

if ( $posts ) {
    $str = '<ul>';

    foreach ($posts as $post ) {
        //Do your stuffs
    }

    $str .= '</ul>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: the php array adam used was correct. it's the [5.4+ shorthand array syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-56).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at the code. I tried this, and fiddled with it but couldn't get it to work. Mayeenul Islam's solution worked however.